# For some reason, my footer isn't very mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

90% of my website is Mobile-Friendly (everything resizes and such), but for some reason my footer is being basically completely cut off on mobile.

The way I have it setup [currently](https://www.factionhouse.org/squallz/) is exactly how I would like it to be setup. This is what it looks like on mobile: [image: mobile view (can see the top of the footer)]

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navigation .nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrapper').toggleClass('open');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.navigation ul li .home a:not(.navigation .nav-toggle)').on('click', function() {
    $('.navigation ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.navigation ul li.home a').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("../images/bg.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.navigation ul li {
  padding: 17px 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.4s;
  -o-transition: color 0.4s;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  color: #00D5C2;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 115%;
  display: block;
}

.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 220px;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.side-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.side-nav ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.outerwrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-100);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper.open {
  transform: translateX(220px);
  background-color: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.6);
}

.side-nav ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.side-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.side-nav.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.navigation .nav-toggle {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: -5em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.footerinfo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footerinfo p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  ;
}

.navigation ul li a.active {
  color: #00F0DB;
}

#logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footerlogo img {
  margin-bottom: -65px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.about-btn {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.4s;
  -o-transition: color 0.4s;
  transition: color 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  transition: border-color 0.4s;
  font-size: 135%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.about-btn a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.4s;
  -o-transition: color 0.4s;
  transition: color 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.4s;
  transition: border-color 0.4s;
  color: #3A9DA4;
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: solid #3A9DA4 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0, 4s;
}

.about-btn li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-btn a:hover {
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: scale(1, 1)
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navigation ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation .nav-toggle {
    display: inline;
  }
  .about-btn a {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerwrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="side-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Repo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
        <li class="pluginrequests"><a href="request">Request Plugin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-toggle">&#9776</li>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="repo"><a href="#">Repo</a></li>
        <li class="pluginrequests"><a href="request">Request Plugin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Squallz Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="about-btn">
      <li><a href="about">About Me</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footerinfo">
      <p>Copyright Squallz 2017. Personal website by <b>Squallz</b></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your css and view again in your mobileL

> .outerwrapper {
>       height: 100%!important;
>   }

Comment: That is giving me a while gap at the bottom now where the footer should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the css of the footer class to:

```css
z-index: 999 !important;
position: fixed !important;
 bottom:0 !important;
 background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.2);
```

Comment: If I add more content, will it expand? Also, on mobile now there is a big white space behind the footer if I scroll down (the background isnt big enough or something)

Comment: Still stuck trying to get it how I want it